# How to read CSV data from a Clob column in Oracle using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql

I'm getting a clob as parameter from a procedure and it contains a CSV file. I need to read this data and load it into another Oracle table.

Could someone please explain how to do this.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? It might have an impact on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Oracle has no ready made goodies for this. One promising candidate is [DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23448/d_util.htm#i1002468), but it's [heavily limited](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1415803954123) to a very special task making it no-option. So you have to roll your sleeves and make your own.

Your specification is a bit vague, but one option is a `SPLIT` function:

```
create table so18t (
  id number,
  csv clob
);

insert all
into so18t values(1,'1,2,3'||chr(10)||
                    '40,5,6'||chr(10)||
                    '700,80,9'||chr(10))
into so18t values(2,'aaa,bbb,ccc'||chr(10)||
                    'ddd,eee,fff'||chr(10)||
                    'ggg,hhh,iii'||chr(10))
select 1 from dual;

declare
  v_lines jh_util.stringlist_t;
  v_values jh_util.stringlist_t;
begin
  for rec in (select * from so18t order by id) loop
    v_lines := jh_util.split(rec.csv, chr(10));
    for i in v_lines.first .. v_lines.last loop
      dbms_output.put_line('line ' || i || ':');
      v_values := jh_util.split(v_lines(i));
      /* Do what you want with the values - I just print them */
      for j in v_values.first .. v_values.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line('v_values(' || j || ') = ' || v_values(j));
      end loop;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
show errors
```

Prints:

```
line 1:
v_values(1) = 1
v_values(2) = 2
v_values(3) = 3
line 2:
v_values(1) = 40
v_values(2) = 5
v_values(3) = 6
line 3:
v_values(1) = 700
v_values(2) = 80
v_values(3) = 9
line 1:
v_values(1) = aaa
v_values(2) = bbb
v_values(3) = ccc
line 2:
v_values(1) = ddd
v_values(2) = eee
v_values(3) = fff
line 3:
v_values(1) = ggg
v_values(2) = hhh
v_values(3) = iii

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Of cource Oracle doesn't provide split but [SO helps](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplsql%5D+split). In the example above I have used my own one.

Other interesting resources:

- [Parsing CSV string](http://radino.eu/2009/01/01/parsing-csv-list/)
- [CSV - comma separated values - and PL/SQL](http://plsql.wikidot.com/forum/t-41518)
- [Converting delimited lists to collections (and vice versa)](http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/delimited_lists_to_collections.html)
- [Ask Tom "DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE limitations ?"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1415803954123)

Comment: Could you also post your JH_UTIL.SPLIT() function?

Comment: @davor I won't post it here but it's available in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/janihur/orasql-ex/src/c39936d5c35b/packages/?at=default)

Answer (score 2):

Do not export the data to a file.

You will need to convert the clob into something useful, parse it, then write to the other table.  Here is the steps you need to do:

1. Convert the Clob from a Clob to a something useful.  CLOB.getCharacterStream() seems useful.
2. Parse the CSV data from the converted Clob object.  `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(the_reader_from_getCharacterStream);` ftw
3. Store the desired data in the other table.

[Oracle's CLOB Object](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/CLOB.html) provides some useful methods.
`CSVReader` is from [Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an immediate way of parsing a clob as a CSV, but Oracle provides a number of tools for working with CSV **files** such as [External Tables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm) and [SQL*Loader](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm).

So an approach might be to:

1. Export the clob as a file using [DBMS_LOB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm) and [UTL_FILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm)
2. Load the file using one of the CSV tools mentioned above.